# VBA to set any negative series to the secondary axis

Tags: vba

I have the following grid of data which I am charting in a stacked area chart and I would like to make any negative variable a secondary axis variable

```
Year   | var 1  | var 2  | var 3  |
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
2012   | 73.97% | 7.70%  | -0.86% |
2013   | 74.49% | 7.46%  | -0.76% |
2014   | 73.60% | 7.48%  | -0.82% |
2015   | 71.87% | 7.01%  | -0.75% |
2016   | 64.96% | 5.18%  | -0.75% |
```

I have put together the following VBA which I have assigned to a developer button on the same tab as my stacked area chart but I keep getting erros saying that the SeriesCollection function is not defined. Any ideas? Ideally the stacked area chart would reside in its own tab:

```
Sub TesNegs()
    Dim n As Series
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    For Each n In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(n).Values) < 0 Then
            n.AxisGroup = 2
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: To help us get closer to the cause of that, are you sure the chart is selected when this code executes?  May have to refer to the chart directly.  Also, does the chart already have the 2nd group set elsewhere?  [see this one if not] (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/512624-adding-new-series-chart-using-visual-basic-applications.html)

Comment: Hi @JimmySmith - Ideally the chart would be referred to directly but I wasn't entirely sure how to do that once the chart is on its own tab. The chart will have some series set to the secondary axis sometimes and not have anything set to the secondary axis sometimes - depends on the data each time I run it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim n As Series
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select

' set any negative series to the secondary axis
For Each n In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    Dim Max As Double
    Max = 0
    For Each Value In n.Values
        If Value > Max Then
            Max = Value
        End If
    Next Value
    If Max = 0 Then
        n.AxisGroup = 2
    End If
Next n
```